# How to merge the datadir with .bitcoin directory?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin.conf

I changed the path of `datadir` in **bitcoin.conf** from **.bitcoin** directory to somewhere else.

Now that I need to backup my blockchain data, I want to have both **.bitcoin** and blockchain data together.

Assuming all bitcoin-core services are off, How should move the blockchain data properly?

###### datadir contents:

```
==== Files ====
anchors.dat
banlist.dat
debug.log
fee_estimates.dat
.lock
mempool.dat
nano.save
peers.dat
settings.json
.swp

==== Folders ====
blocks
chainstate
indexes
wallets
```

###### .bitcoin contents:

```
==== Files ====
anchors.dat
banlist.dat
bitcoin.conf
debug.log
fee_estimates.dat
.lock
mempool.dat
peers.dat
settings.json

==== Folders ====
blocks
chainstate
wallets
```

Comment: Why don't you make a symbolic link from `datadir/blocks` to `.bitcoin/blocks` (assuming you are not using Windows)?

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin I want to backup on an NTFS external hard drive and I want it all to be together